# File and directory permissions

Tags: linux, files, permissions, directory, umask

I am learning umask command , and I get few questions. So:
1.For files and directories default permissions is 666 and 777
how can I config the default permission, specifically where is configuration file for default permissions.
2 The umask command is reduce  permissions, how to ADD permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

The `umask` takes away - correct.  But it takes away from everyone having access to everything.

```
user@darkstar ~ $ umask
0022
user@darkstar ~ $ touch umasktestfile
user@darkstar ~ $ mkdir umasktestdir
user@darkstar ~ $ umask 0000
user@darkstar ~ $ umask
0000
user@darkstar ~ $ touch umasktestfile2
user@darkstar ~ $ mkdir umasktestdir2
user@darkstar ~ $ ls -ld umasktest*
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Dec 26 19:07 umasktestdir
drwxrwxrwx 2 user user 4096 Dec 26 19:08 umasktestdir2
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 Dec 26 19:07 umasktestfile
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user    0 Dec 26 19:08 umasktestfile2
user@darkstar ~ $ umask 0022
user@darkstar ~ $ umask
0022
user@darkstar ~ $
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no global configuration file for file permissions. The permissions are determined by the `mode` parameter to the system calls creating the file or directory, and it is up to the application what to put there. Before the file or directory is created, the mode is modified by the process's umask.